# Apache in Debian Jessie - still get message You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache, debian

The same virtual config i apache wheezy works right.
For example:

ServerName lgbs
    ServerAlias www.lgbs

```
DocumentRoot /home/vdomain/app/web
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

<Directory /home/vdomain/app/web>
    # enable the .htaccess rewrites
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

But on Debian testing 'Jessie' i still get message:

Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Debian) Server at test Port 80

Of course a check file permision and i set rwx for evryones and owner and group is www-data.
Thanks for help

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 6):

This drove me crazy for a couple of hours. Apparently in 2.4.9 ( I upgraded from 2.2.2 ) there is a "Require all granted" that you need to add to each directory.

In my http.conf:

```
#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

So basically what I had to do was:

```
<Directory "/Users/johndoe/Sites">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```