# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache, debian

I'm trying to set up a webserver on my VPS (Running Debian 7). I have installed apache and configured it. However, when I try to connect to my IP I am faced with a 403 forbidden error saying that I don't have access to / on the server. I have attempted to set it up so that when connecting the webserver should direct to the directory: /home/webmaster/website. My main apache.conf file is as follows: http://pastebin.com/zgyik39y
and my site config, called "web.conf" is: http://pastebin.com/jpRJAaCw I don't know what to do, I've tried many suggestions on here and in other places and none so far have worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache in Debian Jessie - still get message You don't have permission to access / on this server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905936/apache-in-debian-jessie-still-get-message-you-dont-have-permission-to-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 18 of web.conf should be:

```
Allow from all
```

For apache 2.2 or:

```
Require all granted
```

For apache 2.4